# NSOutlineView highlight style

Tags: nsoutlineview

I want to implement an NSTableView programmatically (Swift 4), not using Storyboards. If I were using a Storyboard (which I am not -- I want my outline in plain code), I would use the 'Source List' setting in the Attributes Inspector. See the screenshot below.

[image]

How can/should I code my NSOutlineView in Swift to use the 'Source List Highlight Style'?

Comment: Does `NSTableView` have a property which sounds like highlight style?

Comment: Obviously I checked the documentation. I would not ask for help had I have found a reference there...

Comment: How about `selectionHighlightStyle`? and searching for "sourcelist" leads to `NSTableView.SelectionHighlightStyle`.

Comment: Right, how could I have missed that? I will make an appointment with my optician. Thanks for pointing it out to me!